# How to find my path of key file in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I read many similar content but I couldn't find a solution.

I am a flutter developer, yesterday i signed an android application and sent it to google play.
I cannot find the key file I created or I am not sure if its name is the key.

I created it yesterday on this mac computer , but today there is no such file. I only have a file named 'private_key.pepk' on my desktop.

Can I find out where the path I chose when signing for the first time from my Android project? i need your help

Answer (score 0):

Android developer that hasn't signed a Flutter app yet, but in build.gradle you should have something like this:

```
signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("EITHER A PATH OR RELATIVE PATH")
            storePassword sPassword
            keyAlias kAlias
            keyPassword kPassword
        }
    }
```